# List view column re-order logic

Tags: 2007, list-view

Has any one implemented a custom re-ordering logic similar to the one as seen on the view settings page of list/library which lets the user to specify the order of the columns.

I tried searching for the inbuilt JS function in MOSS but was unable to find any.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Let's all show our appreciation by upvoting helpful answers. There's five answers here, mostly from experts, and at the time I write this none of them have a single upvote. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably implement custom order logic by modifying the XSLT of a dataviewwebpart in SharePoint Designer.

Are you able to give details of what kind of order logic you need?

Comment: I have a couple of custom columns to be displayed in a custom web part. I want to give the user ability able to set (via an application page) the order in which he wants to see the columns in the web part

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement something like that in a web part, using the re-ordering from the /_layouts/formEdt.aspx page, similar to the one on the view page you looked at. The problem ended up being that it would do the re-order client side, then post the update to the server extensions url (owssvr.dll). That didn't play well with the custom web part editor i had.

At that point I abandoned that idea, and just did the field order as a simple comma separated list. It was easy to sell to stakeholders as the content query web part does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery, as many people write things to sit on top of it ([like this List reorder script](http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/)). You'd obviously need to modify it to save your values. Please note that the component listed below doesn't create form items that will submit via a post/get so you would need to add that in yourself.

From a design perspective I would stick everything into a dropdown control and at worst, implement my own "move up / move down" logic which is then parsed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Re-ordering logic which you see in view settings page can be attached to a list for two purposes:

1. to order list items
2. to order columns of list

What kind  of re-ordering are you expecting?

Comment: As i mentioned in the comments in response to James answer, I have a custom web part that displays some business information in combination of some fields. Now I want to give the user tha ability to arrange the order of these columns as displayed on the web part.